# Require coupon code at checkout for WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to force customers to use any valid coupon code at checkout in my Woo store. The item is free but it's for my restaurant which I'd like the customer to come into the restaurant and allow us to input the coupon code or tell them the code for successful checkout.

The category is "Redeem" which is a free coupon category in my WooCommerce store, but I'd like for clients to not redeem them outside of the store, since I have set the use of the coupons once, or purchase of products once per account.

I tried using this code but it might be outdated since it doesn't allow to get to checkout page.

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'mandatory_coupon_code' );
function mandatory_coupon_code() {
$product_categories = array( 'redeem' ); // Category ID or slug of targeted category
$coupon_code = '0001'; // The required coupon code

$coupon_applied = in_array( strtolower($coupon_code), WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons() );

// Loop through cart items
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
if( has_term( $product_categories, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) && ! $coupon_applied ) {
wc_clear_notices(); // Clear all other notices
// Avoid checkout displaying an error notice
wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'The product"%s" requires a coupon for checkout.', $cart_item['data']->get_name() ), 'error' );
break; // stop the loop
}
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome! The code you provided doesn't look like it's been updated at all for your use case. What is the actual coupon code? What's the actual product?

Comment: Sorry I updated the code I used. I had pasted a different one from a site.